# Integration testings on swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an app that I'm testing right now, 
a big part of my app is using an enclosed library that does REST calls to a server to update and take out data and then is doing stuff with that data.

most of these "calls" are happening inside my interactor. and in order to check it, I need to call them.

calling this functions doesn't return me the reply i usually get from them, and i looked for an integration testing tutorial or something for xcode or swift, and couldn't find one.

am I approaching this wrong ? or what am I doing wrong?

here is an example of one of my interactor functions:

```
 func SDKAuthenticatedSussfuly(_ errorHandle: @escaping (String) -> Void, _ completion: @escaping (AWSDKConsumer) -> Void) {

        AWSDKAuthenticationService.authenticateConsumer(withUsername: sdkUsername, password: sdkPassword, consumerAuthKey: nil) {[weak self] (result, error) in


            if (result != nil) {

                guard let consumer = result as? AWSDKConsumer else {
                    NSLog("Unexpected authentication result")
                    return
                }

                isUserLoggedIn = true
                completion(consumer)

            } else {
               errorHandle(WhiteLabeler.localizedStringForKey(key: "loginScreen_error_wrongUsername", comment: "-", defaultValue: "Wrong Username or Password"))
            }

        }

    }
```

and an example of a unitest i'm writing (that fails due to the rest call doesn't go inside the callback):

```
func testLoginScreen() {
        let homeInteractor: HomeInteractor = HomeInteractor ()

        homeInteractor.initSDK()

        sleep(4)

        homeInteractor.loginUser(userNameText: "a@a.com", passwordText: "Password1")

        XCTAssertEqual(isInitlized, true)

    }
```

Comment: Important: you have to recognize between *unit* test and *integration* test; Do you you want to test the functionality of your code assuming that the response is returned as it should, or do you want to test the result of the response itself?

Comment: integration tests, to test the login function as i showed it the function.

Comment: Some tips: 1) declare `homeInteractor` globally in the test class and initialize it in the `setUp` method. 2) If you are aiming to do *integration* test(s), don't do `sleep(4)` because you would need to deal with the response regardless of the consumed time to receive (do not try to *mock* it when deal with integration tests). 3) Use `expectations`, check: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations

Comment: thank you @AhmadF also in that guide form what i inderstand, that will tell me to bring the actual AWSDK library to my unitests call and do a Login function there, 
and not to test my login funciton in the interactor, is there a way for me to test that in the interactor itself ?

Comment: As you said the function exists in the interactor,  thus you should test *the returned result* from this function which is called via an interactor instance. So you don't have to test AWSDK directly. The point is to makes sure that the response has a specific from.

Comment: @AhmadF yes i agree but the document you sent me will do exactly the oposit of what you mention here, it will take the AWSDK Directly into the unitesting, and not call the function in the interactor. which is exactly what i should avoid right ?

Comment: Its not about directly testing `URLSession` nor your AWSDK, the purpose of it is to test async code; In your case, since the interactor is the responsible for this you could use expectations to test it, which is sensible.

Comment: @AhmadF could u add a code example of what you mean ? using the function i added here ?  and write it as an answer ?